# New job starts before end of current job's notice period

Tags: job-offer, negotiation, manager, notice-period

My current job has a notice period of 3 months, but I can negotiate this if my boss agrees to it. I have a job offer, and they want me to start in one month.

What is the best approach to handle this situation? Do I negotiate the notice period with my boss before or after accepting the new job?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the rationale for 'Don't quit your job until you have a new one'?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/58396/what-is-the-rationale-for-dont-quit-your-job-until-you-have-a-new-one)

Comment: Where are you? If you're in the US, you're subject to at will employment. Are you in the UK? Are you under any contractual obligations?

Comment: I don't think this matches the linked duplicate. Joe's answer below is textbook for this scenario and quite a bit different. At best the linked question should be added to his answer under the "if they won't budge on the one month notice" hypothetical.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but an answer I wrote addressing the issue specifically in the Indian IT context might be somewhat useful to you. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/78717/3192

Answer (score 10):

> What is the best process? Do I accept job and then negotiate leaving
>   time with current boss? Or do I negotiate leaving time with my boss
>   before accepting the job?

You accept the job but tell your new employer that your current company requires a 3-month notice. If 3-month notices are standard in your part of the world they should understand, even though they would prefer that you start in 1 month.

You also tell them that you will attempt to negotiate an earlier leave date if possible.

Then, you talk to your current boss, give your notice, and attempt to negotiate an earlier leave date.

Once you and your current boss have agree on a leave date (early or otherwise), you inform your new employer of the anticipated start date.

Finally, you work your notice period to the best of your ability, leave, and join your new employer.

If for some reason your new employer absolutely will not hire you unless you can start in 1 month, you may be out of luck. You could choose to attempt to negotiate an early leave from your current employer without having a formal job acceptance, but that could be very tricky. Likely it won't come to that.